# Views multiple Exposed Filters

Tags: views, search

I have a view with three exposed filters like age, gender and city. Is it possible that, if I select for example "city = NY" and there are no "ages = 14-16" that this filter option will not be shown? I guess I want my exposed filters to narrow down each other (to work as a facet search). Is this possible?

Comment: It would be possible for a hierarchal filter https://drupal.org/project/shs

Answer (score 1):

Try the [views hacks](https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) module (really not the best name for a module).

Specifically see the part on the project page at https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks#views_filters_selective