# Views 'Search terms' exposed filter not working as expected

Tags: views

I have a view that displays a list of people. I want to allow the list to be filtered by its search terms, so I've added a 'Search terms' exposed filter. I'm using hook_form_alter() to override this exposed filter so the user can select from a list of countries, so they can "Search by country". This just passes a country name in as the exposed filter value. I've added a second 'Search terms' exposed filter so a user can further filter by keyword.

This doesn't seem to work as expected. When I choose 'Australia' from the first filter, I get 39 results, which is correct. When I then enter 'Astronomy' into the second filter, I get no results. I expected to get back 1 result, a user whose node contains both 'Australia' and 'Astronomy'. If I leave one filter blank and enter 'Australia Astronomy' into the other, I get the correct user result.

Is there a way to make this work the way I want to? The first exposed filter has to be filtering on a node's indexed content (find country mentioned anywhere in the node), so I can't filter on a single field here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind posting 2 things? A) a screenshot of the view settings. B) The query being ran in views. You can turn on queries in the Views settings.

Comment: Here's an export of the view: https://gist.github.com/vinmassaro/f746f2cf77085fe89a45

Here is an example of the query being run when searching for 'Australia' and 'astronomy': https://gist.github.com/vinmassaro/256947a0fbdc0647d519

Comment: Why don't you simply add a screenshot of your view, so that one can get the idea?

Answer (score 2):

The mistake comes from the WHERE conditions :

```
AND(( (search_index.type = 'node') AND( (search_index.word = 'australia') ))AND( (search_index.type = 'node') AND( (search_index.word = 'astronomy') ))))
```

This will always return empty result ! Not convinced?  simply try

```
    SELECT * FROM `search_index` WHERE `word` = 'Australia' AND `word` = 'Astronomy'
```

So you'll need a subquery here : for the sake of example, let's say :

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid
FROM node 
LEFT JOIN search_index ON node.nid = search_index.sid
WHERE node.status = '1' 
AND  search_index.word = 'Astronomy'
AND sid IN ( 
    SELECT sid FROM `search_index` WHERE `word` = 'Australia' 
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Now to get it I suggest that you implement [hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7). First, call Views API :

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_api().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3, //Views 3
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'YOUR_MODULE'),
  );
}
```

And then the tricky part

```
function YOUR_MODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if($view->name == 'YOUR_VIEW' && (count($view->YOUR_EXPOSED_FIELD) > 1 ) )  {
    dpm($view); //OR dpm($query); 
    //alter your query here ; you'll have to debug and tune the following lines
    //short one
    $query->where ... = ...
    //alternative one
    foreach($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        //not sure from here, use `dpm ()` on your own objects            
        if($condition['field'] == 'search_index.word') {
          $condition = array(
            'field' => 'search_index.sid',
            'value' => db_query('SELECT sid FROM `search_index` WHERE `word` = '.$view->YOUR_EXPOSED_FIELD),
            'operator' => 'IN',
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views.inc and it will be
>   auto-loaded. MODULENAME.views.inc must be in the directory specified
>   by the 'path' key returned by MODULENAME_views_api(), or the same
>   directory as the .module file, if 'path' is unspecified.

**EDIT** : as per Vincent, used `add_where_expression` for the subquery and unset the original part of the query related to that search

```
$query->add_where_expression('3', "sid IN (SELECT sid FROM search_index WHERE search_index.word = '{$search_value}')");
//sthing like
unset($query->where[1]['conditions'][0]);
```

Comment: This looks like it's on the right track - I will need to review. Does this look like a bug? I had opened an issue in the Views issue queue on Drupal.org as well.

Comment: not at all. Views simply doesn't manage sub queries out of the box. There was an interesting post about that from merlinofchaos or another Drupal team guy, but I don't find it to send you the link now.

Comment: Ok, I `dpm()`ed into this and the problem I originally ran into is that `$condition['field']` is a DatabaseCondition object. I'm  not sure how to get into it to modify.

Comment: $conditions is protected but conditions() isn't...try $conditions = &$condition->conditions(); and manipulate them directly ;)

Comment: Ok, I'm close! Here's a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7quu5ll4vvydf5r/Screenshot%202014-07-21%2014.53.16.png) of what I see for: https://gist.github.com/vinmassaro/e04eb1181824561b3f35

Comment: Vincent, just to make sure, is your module really called my_module ? Sometimes we miss evidence... Then as I can't dpm() your own config it's quite hard to help you in details. if you feel blocked don't misconsider trying the alternative `unset($query->where[x]['conditions'][y])` for the 2nd `AND search_index.word =` condition then some `$query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['value'] = 'BUILD YOUR SUBQUERY HERE';` ... Good luck. When you got it, you can post an answer with final code to share to help further :)

Comment: I just renamed the function for the example, but you can see that it is close. I'm not sure what the query should be, can you help with that? Should I just be unsetting one of the conditions and joining its value with the first condition so that the search is for 'Australia astronomy'?

Comment: Vincent, You have to unset one of the `AND( (search_index.word = 'foo')` and then add a condition similar to my subquery example : `AND sid IN ( SELECT sid FROM search_index WHERE word = 'Australia')` replacing Australia of course by the keyword argument sent to the query. Is that clear ? You can find all the info with some btw `dpm($query->arguments()); dpm($query->conditions()); dpm($query->where);` you can see the full string with `dpm((string) $query);` . Hope it helps

Comment: How do I add this correctly as a condition in hook_views_query_alter()? 

`AND sid IN ( SELECT sid FROM search_index WHERE search_index.word = 'astronomy'))))`

The $conditions['value'] array fails with your db_query() example. It doesn't seem like db_query needs to be in there, just the text of the query. Thanks.

Comment: if you can please help me work through this I can mark this as an accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: I believe you have to get an array first `$subquery = db_query("SELECT sid FROM search_index WHERE search_index.word = 'foo'");` and then pass this array into `AND sid IN ($subquery->sid)` or smthing like that, instead of writing raw subquery in the condition. Does this work ?

Comment: Vincent, did you manage to write the query alter ? I've got an UI alternative that might solve it easier :) check [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate). it works with textfields. Also send me some screen captures of your dpm() s if you wish to and your code, as I'm interested in your progress but I can't promise cause I'm really timeless now.

Comment: I ended up actually needing to use `$query->add_where_expression()` inside `hook_views_query_alter()` in order to add the extra query. I take the value of the text search field, and supply it like this: `$query->add_where_expression('3', "sid IN (SELECT sid FROM search_index WHERE search_index.word = '{$search_value}')");`. I then unset the original search field where query.

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80300/views-multiple-exposed-filters) the [Views Selective Filters](https://drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters) module gets your "exposed filters to narrow each other down (to work as a facet search)."

Comment: Thanks, but this module is about reducing the results displayed in an exposed filter. In my issue, I am having a problem with the query being sent.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in another context with a custom entity. To avoid too much details I describe it with a common example: I needed to find nodes which referenced to node A AND node B. It was neccessary to get this by two exposed filters where the user was able to search for different search pairs like "show me nodes referencing to node B AND node A" or "referencing to node C and node E". The problem was the resulting query.

My solution was to use a second relationship (created in a custom module with `function MYMODULE_views_data_alter(&$data)`, getting it into the view and connecting it to the second filter. I am not quite sure if that really works in your case with the Drupal search filter but hopefully it gives you a hint in a direction of a solution

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can yourself solve this by using function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query).

If i have to i will use it like in template.php of site theme:

```
function Yourthemename_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)
  {
    //firstly get name by printing like print $view->name;
    //Now use condition like following
    if($view->name=='viewname')
    {
      //Now Print here $query like:-echo "<pre>"; print_r($query);
      //Their you got conditions that you have used as exposed filter in views.
      //After entering 'Australia Astronomy' in second filter checkout the condition that is printing using print_r;
      //Now Alter the condition their accoring to this.like:-

      Query->where[]='YOUR_Conditon';


    }
  }
```

You have to change condtions accoring to result you want.You have to try it yourself.we will solve it if we have you have provided exported view code.